# Retrieve the last line of a file from cURL

Tags: php, curl

Code is below. This grabs the webpage into `$result` just fine. I need to grab just the last line of the data so that I can then manipulate it. What's the best way to do this?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('https://waterdata.usgs.gov/tx/nwis/uv?cb_00060=on&cb_00065=on&format=rdb&site_no=08047500&period=&begin_date=2019-07-18&end_date=2019-07-25');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I would suggest doing a HEAD request to figure out the `Length` of the response.  Then, download say the last kilobyte or two and parse the last line from there, to save data.  However, this server doesn't return the `Length` when you make a `HEAD` request.  Therefore, you'll just have to download the whole thing.

Fortunately, it isn't very long.  You can use RegEx for this job:

```
preg_match('/\n(.*)$/i', $result, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// get the lines in an array
$lines = explode("\n",$str);

// get the last line
$line = end($lines);
```